# Class Property inside Class On Separate Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a host class which launches an instance of another class on a new thread like so:

I am referencing this MSDN article according to which, Class2.P1 should NOT be null.
LINK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx

Am I missing anything obvious?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Host().DoWork();
        }
    }
    public class Host {

      Class2Parent c = new Class2();
      Thread t;
      public void DoWork() {
      c.P1 = new Class3();
      t = new Thread(c.Start);
      t.Start();
      }
    }

    public class Class2Parent {
      public Class3 P1 = null;
        public virtual void Start() {}
    }

   public class Class2 : Class2Parent {
       public Class3 P1 = null;          
       public override void Start() {
      Console.WriteLine(P1 == null); // this is always true
      } 
   }   

   public class Class3 
   {}
}
```

Comment: I don't know if you're missing something but your Host class is missing methods

Comment: What is your actual code? You are'nt starting thread t at all.

Comment: You are not starting the thread

Comment: So sorry for the code. I just corrected it. The thread is definitely being started but the reference property P1 is still NULL.

Comment: This still cannot be the real code - it won't compile! So how do you know, P1 is null?

Comment: I simplified the code, my actual code is much more complex but the basic principle is the same. Let me just make sure that it compiles.

When I instantiate a variable and set its reference based property and start it on a new thread, that property is still appearing as NULL inside the class being run.

Comment: Oh shoot now it works :-( Maybe there is more going on in my actual code .. sorry about this.

Comment: So minimize the actual code until the problem disappears...

Comment: Yeah, I am stepping through it. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok I found the bug. I had defined the same property in the parent class (Class2Parent) as well as the derived class Class2. Removing the duplicated property from Class2 (property P1) solved the issue. 

Thanks all for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a new thread using a timer variable just like that :

```
private Timer m_RequestTimer;

public void Begin()
{
            // Timer check
            if (m_RequestTimer != null)
            {
                m_RequestTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
                m_RequestTimer.Dispose();
                m_RequestTimer = null;
            }
m_RequestTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(obj => { c.Start(); }, null, 250, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        }
}
```

where m_RequestTimer is an attribute of your class host and Begin a method of Host.

I hope it will help you =)

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: In his original post the thread wasn't started so I show him a way to start a thread.